# Extracting Gzip files from requests with multithreading

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-requests

I'm trying to extract a bunch (62.000) gzip files. In these files is a text document formatted as JSON. Right now I'm downloading all these files with the requests module with multithreading:

```
def fetch_file(url,filename):
    try:
        html = requests.get(url,stream=True,allow_redirects=True)
        open('Streams Total Daily/'+filename+'.json.gz','wb').write(html.content)
        return html.status_code
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
       return e

def get_streams():
    threads = []
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        for uri in country_uris:
            split = uri.split('/')
            filename = 'streams_'+split[1] + '_' +split[4]+'_'+split[5]+'_'+split[6] + '_'+ split[7]
            url = f"{link}{uri}?access_token={access_token}"
            threads.append(executor.submit(fetch_file,url,filename))
        
        for task in as_completed(threads):
            print(task.result())

get_streams()
```

I have some code that can loop through the folder where the files are placed, but this takes a long time with 62000 files. I've tried some versions passing response.content through gzip.GzipFile(), but this just gives me empty files.

```
def fetch_file(url,filename):
    try:
        html = requests.get(url,stream=True,allow_redirects=True)
        gz = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=html.content)
        with open('test/'+filename + '.json','wb') as out:
            out.write(gz.read())
        return html.status_code
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
       return e

def get_streams():
    threads = []
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        for uri in country_uris:
            split = uri.split('/')
            filename = 'streams_'+split[1] + '_' +split[4]+'_'+split[5]+'_'+split[6] + '_'+ split[7]
            url = f"{link}{uri}?access_token={access_token}"
            threads.append(executor.submit(fetch_file,url,filename))
        
        for task in as_completed(threads):
            print(task.result())
get_streams()
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to handle this? Any suggestions or solutions are much appreciated!

Comment: If you have all .gz files in the folder - can't you just use a system command to unzip them all? like gunzip *.gz

Comment: What do you need python for in this case? If it is processing of the resulting json file, your script may not need to do the actual unzipping... you could use `bash` or your shell of choice to loop through the directory unzipping with `tar` or `gunzip`, then pass the resulting files to your Python code.

OR you can try looking at using [asyncio + aiohttp](https://www.proxiesapi.com/blog/asynchronous-web-scraping-with-python-aiohttp-and-.html.php) to perform the requests, and then process the responses (zipped files)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me, in the end, was the Zlib module. First getting a bytes response with `response.content`, then decompressing the data with `zlib.decompress(response.content, 16 +zlib.MAX_WBITS)` and finally writing the decompressed data to a `.json` file:

```
 def get_files(i):
        url = f"{url}{i}"
        elements = i.split('/') 
        name = elements[1] + '_' +elements[3] + '_' + elements[4] + '_' + elements[5]+ '_' + elements[6] + '_' +elements[7]
        try:
            response = requests.get(url=url,headers=headers,allow_redirects=True,).content
            decompressed_data = zlib.decompress(response, 16 + zlib.MAX_WBITS)
            with open(f"Streams Total Daily/{name}.json",'wb') as out:
                out.write(decompressed_data)

        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            return e
    
    def runner():
        threads =[]
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
            for i in country_files:
                threads.append(executor.submit(get_files,i))
runner()
```